# Using timezone and day light saving with epoch time

Tags: time, epoch

I've a epoch time it's seconds or milliseconds format. How do I get time zone and day light saving details from that epoch time? Or do I have to pass as a separate value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An epoch time in second or millisecond resolution is just a number. And a number cannot hold more than **ONE** information, here the elapsed time since an epoch.

**Time zone or daylight saving details must therefore be transmitted as extra information.** Keep also in mind that a time zone is often pretty complex (has an ID, a name, a history of offset transitions etc.) so most time zones cannot just be expressed as simple numbers.

By the way, I cannot give more concrete answer how to transmit extra details like time zones since you have not even told us which programming language or tool you use.